# Multi-Variable Switch Statement with "and"/"or" JAVA

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am new to coding an am working on coding a game, where each player has four stats: `str`, `con`, `dex`, and `int`. With a specific race of player, the user chooses two stats that increase by two, and in turn the other two stats get decreased by two. Currently I am determining which stats should by decreased based on what was chosen to increase. `stat1` is the name of the first stat the user increases, and `stat2` is the name of the second stat, and these two stats are taken from user input. This how I currently have it as an if/else if/else. I was wondering if it could be written easily as a switch statement.

```
if((stat1.startsWith("con") && stat2.startsWith("dex"))||(stat1.startsWith("dex") && stat2.startsWith("con")))
{
    addStat("int",-2);
    addStat("str",-2);
}
else if((stat1.startsWith("con") && stat2.startsWith("int"))||(stat1.startsWith("int") && stat2.startsWith("con")))
{
    addStat("dex",-2);
    addStat("str",-2);
}
else if((stat1.startsWith("con") && stat2.startsWith("str"))||(stat1.startsWith("str") && stat2.startsWith("con")))
{
    addStat("dex",-2);
    addStat("int",-2);
}
else if((stat1.startsWith("dex") && stat2.startsWith("int"))||(stat1.startsWith("int") && stat2.startsWith("dex")))
{
    addStat("con",-2);
    addStat("str",-2);
}
else if((stat1.startsWith("dex") && stat2.startsWith("str"))||(stat1.startsWith("str") && stat2.startsWith("dex")))
{
    addStat("int",-2);
    addStat("con",-2);
}
else if((stat1.startsWith("str") && stat2.startsWith("int"))||(stat1.startsWith("int") && stat2.startsWith("str")))
{
     addStat("dex",-2);
     addStat("con",-2);
}
```

Comment: The switch statement takes 1 variable and its possible values, but here you have 2 that are related, so it won't work.

Comment: you can nest `switch` blocks, but this would not necessarily make it simpler. Maybe it would be simpler to map the attributes on `int`s (e.g. `0` for `str`, `1` for `dex`,...) and then record which attributes are increased by 2and decrease the rest 2.

Comment: I answered that you can not do this with switch, but you probably want to move those 'stat1' and 'stat2' into a collection and use iteration. Those numbers 1 & 2 already signify you may need that for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 4):

No, not as a switch statement. But it can be much more concise by just using a collection and a loop:

```
Set<String> allStats = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("dex", "str", "con", "int"));
Set<String> increasedStats = new HashSet<>();
// TODO: let the user choose the stats to increase, 
// and store them in increadedStats

// then decrease the two other ones:
for (String stat : allStats) {
    if (!increasedStats.contains(stat)) {
        addStat(stat, -2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest to convert all the values to an enum. It would be better in this case and also allows to use `EnumSet.complementOf`

Comment: Of course, that would be the next logical step. But one thing at a time :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you would define an `enum` and have `stat1` and `stat2` of this enum type than your code could be as simple as:

```
public enum Stat {
    DEX,
    INT,
    STR,
    CON;
}

for(Stat stat : EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(stat1,stat2))) {
    addStat(stat,-2);
}
```

If you find yourself writing such long if-else-trains you should always make a step backwards and reconsider your design.

And maybe it would be better not to have two separate variables `stat1` and `stat2` and just represent it as a collection right from the beginning.

Comment: You was faster than me :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know much about enums, but this seems super useful! and what do you mean by don't have two separate variables?

Comment: @blake In your original code, you wouldn't have `String stat1; String stat2;` but instead have `List<String> stats` where the list has two values in it, which correspond to `stat1` and `stat2`. In my code this  would be `List<Stat> stats`. You might also be able use a `Set` instead of a `List`, but I don't know enough about the overall application to give a clear decision on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to switch more than a single variable. This is documented as follows in the Java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

Sorry you will have to stick to 'else if' for this one.